# Spotify's "Sorry, I could not find this app"

Tags: spotify

As in the API documentation, I have created a `~/Spotify/myapp/index.html` (on a Mac) but when loading `spotify:app:myapp` from the search bar in Spotify (preview version that supports apps) I get a "Sorry, I could not find this app" message.

What am I missing (this should be all for a "Hello World" according to the docs, right? Is there a way I can debug this to better understand the problem?

Comment: Here's how to get started developing locally: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#gettingstarted (but that doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you did not apply for being a developer at Spotify. Do you have a menu item called Develop and have the ability to right-click inside given apps?

If not, you need to have developer capabilities activated by Spotify. You can do so [on their Site](http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/developer-signup/). Your account will probably not be activated instantly.

Comment: This must be it, referencing their tutorial http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/tutorial/ they mention you need to have a developer account.

Comment: I have applied for a dev account a few days ago, but am still waiting for the developer to appear in Spotify. I'll accept when this proves to be the solution.

Comment: My dev account arrived and indeed solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: What if I have the Develop menu item but I'm still getting this message? I have created the directory structure on by Windows and Mac OS but Spotify still cannot find my test app. Also, I have no underscores in my app folder's name.

Comment: For me it took about 30 minutes and a restart of spotify before I was a developer; now it works!

Comment: Today all of a sudden I had lost developer status again. And then 30 minutes (and many spotify restarts) later I was developer again. Just sharing so that you know that you're not going completely crazy if you see this happening to you.....

Comment: I just signed up, and I had to log out then log in to get the developer menu.  Restarting wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a video explaining how to solve this.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paqq3h1UJhU

Basically you need to go to the Spotify.app -> Contents -> Resources -> cef_views ; and drop your stuff in there.

Comment: This works indeed, but every change I make, I need to restart Spotify  to reload it ... I think I'll await my developer account, as in another solution posted here.

Comment: And for windows 7 users the apps has to go to this directory:
C:\Users\---NAME---\AppData\Ro­­aming\Spotify\Data\resources.­z­ip\apps
...And yes it is a zipfile :-s... You have to restart spotify before the app is updated!  -  This is from the comments. What if I do not have a Spotify folder in my AppData folder? I've checked both 32-bit and 64-bit folders.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to keep in mind!  I was trying to create my app with an underscore in the name, and for some reason it choked up the application.  As soon as I removed the underscore and kept it to just letters, it worked fine.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

So according to the docs you posted yourself, you need, in spotifys current form, to name your folder appstore.

> Your application will appear in the sidebar in future builds - for now, please name the folder of your application “appstore” to have it appear in the sidebar. Please name your application accordingly in the manifest, and that very name will appear in the sidebar.

Comment: That should only be the case if you want the app to appear in the sidebar, right? Renaming `myapp` to `appstore` results in the same problem that Spotify cannot find my app.

Comment: have you also named it accordingly in the manifest.json file?

Answer (score 0):

What I got wrong is that insite "Spotify" folder you have to create "Tutorial" folder, in my case all the files were on Spotify and not in Tutorial.